# Adding “save image” javascript button to a php script

Tags: javascript, php, css

This script: https://www.ubergallery.net/
Where there's a demo in mentioned url and a link to download the script.

What I need to add to script is the following:
I just need when clicking an image, I need to have under it in addition to "previous" and "next" buttons, an additional text button or link of which when you click the save image dialog appears to save the current image.

I want to add it after the following javacript:

> current:"image {current} of {total}"

In jquery.colorbox.js

I hope if someone can help with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you not use the `download` attribute on a `href`?

Comment: Just "save as'" or "save image" hotlinked or a button instead.

Comment: Also, please share what you've already attempted. The community here won't write the script for you, we need to see an attempt of some sort :)

Comment: I didn't save those files, but I've added a hotlink after ((current:"image {current} of {total}")) but wasn't able to get the variable of html link of each image which I shall take the image url from.

Comment: you will need to do a bit of JS to refresh the target of the download link each time the image has changed. There's a lot of tutorials online for reading something's source and changing another element's attribute to match on change/click